# calculate de memory used by my services

Tags: c#, web-services, web-applications, memory-management

I have a web aplication that read data from a file using the next code in C#:

```
string [] split_line;
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(data_file);
line = sr.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    dimenc[nn] = new double[dimentions+1];
    for (int m2 = 0; m2 < dimentions; m2++)
    {
        split_line = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '\t' });
        dimenc[nn][m2] = Convert.ToDouble(split_line[m2]);
    }
    nn = nn + 1;
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

my localhost has 8 gb in ram but when it start to read large data files the hole memory starts to be used, reaching the out of memory exception.

let's say one example my file has 10 elements, and 2 dimensions this will make the jagged array like this: `dimen[10][2]` by this the a located physical memory will be 160 bytes, in larger files i reach to have a located physical memory of 1.5 Gb however when i review the physical memory from the task administrator it says that it been used 7.5 Gb or more, so how can this be? is there something i missing to calculate the total amount of memory that it has been used?

Comment: What are the actual dimensions in your production app?  You're storing N*M doubles.  If that's just a few dozen it shouldn't be a problem, but if you're storing billions then obviously it'll take several GB of data; there's no real way around that.

Comment: @Servy yes the jagged array is double to be N*M the max i have tested is [100,000,000][2]; even so this will only take 1.5 gb of physical memory but the task manager indicates that it is been used 7 Gb